# Easy proof or generalization of a fact about sequences of substructures

Tags: logic, solution-verification, model-theory, alternative-proof

This question is inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4822168/). I'm interested in general strategies for showing that a given structure is not expressible as a *set of first-order sentences*. Right now I'm looking for ways of taking infinitely many $L$-structures and stapling them together in such a way that certain properties hold of the result.

So far, I've had the idea of a possibly-infinite sequence of first-order structures, each one a substructure of the next. I'm pretty sure that any sentence that's eventually constantly true in the sequence is true in the resulting limit structure.

My question is twofold:

1. Does the following theorem regarding sequences of substructures hold?
2. Is it an immediate consequence of a more general principle?

---

First, let $A_1, A_2, \cdots$ be a sequence of $L$-structures where $A_i$ is a substructure of $A_{i+1}$.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the limit of the $A_1, A_2, \cdots$ formed by taking the union of their domains and defining the constant, function, and relation symbols in the appropriate way.

Is *every well-formed formula that's true in every structure after a prefix of finite length* true in  $\mathcal{A}$?

First, let's consider the quantifier-free case.

Let $\varphi(\vec{v})$ be a quantifier-free formula. Suppose by way of contrapositive that $\mathcal{A} \not\models \varphi(\vec{v})$ that means there exists a $\vec{w}$ such that $\mathcal{A}, \vec{w} \not\models \varphi(\vec{w})$. $\vec{w}$ is finite, therefore there must exist a $k$ such that $A_k$ and all subsequent structures contain all of $\vec{w}$. $A_k, \vec{w} \not\models \varphi(\vec{w})$ as desired.

Next let's consider the case of a formula with $n$ quantifiers and suppose that the inductive hypothesis holds for all formulas with $n-1$ or fewer quantifiers.

Suppose $\varphi(\vec{v})$ is of the form $[\exists x](\psi(x, \vec{v}))$. Suppose by way of contrapositive that $\mathcal{A} \not\models [\exists x](\psi(x, \vec{v}))$. Thus, there exists a $\vec{w}$ so that $\mathcal{A}, \vec{w} \not\models [\exists x](\psi(x, \vec{w}))$ and thus there exists $\vec{u}$ so that $\mathcal{A}, \vec{u} \not\models \psi(\vec{u})$. Thus, by the inductive hypothesis there exists an $A_k$ such that $A_k, \vec{u} \not\models \psi(\vec{u})$ and hence $A_k \not\models [\exists x](\psi(x, \vec{v})$ as desired.

Suppose $\varphi(\vec{v})$ is of the form $[\forall x](\psi(x, \vec{v}))$, then the inductive hypothesis holds of the formula $\psi(\vec{u})$ where $\vec{u}$ is $x, \vec{v}$ and we're done.

Comment: let $L$ be the language $\{\leqslant\}$. for each $n$, let $A_n$ be the $L$-structure $\{0,\dots,n\}$ with the usual ordering. then every $A_n$ satisfies $\exists x\forall y(y\leqslant x)$, but $\bigcup_n A_n$ does not satisfy it

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Oops, I didn't notice your comment  before I posted my answer with the same counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is false. For example, suppose $A_n = ([n],\leq)$, where $[n]=\{0,\dots n-1\}$. Then $A= \bigcup A_n=(\mathbb{N},\leq)$. Consider the sentence $\varphi:\exists x\forall y\,(y\leq x)$ asserting that there is a greatest element. We have $A_n\models\varphi$ for all $n$, but $A\not\models\varphi$.

The sentences preserved by unions of chains in your sense are exactly the $\forall\exists$-sentences, i.e., those equivalent to a sentence of the form $\forall\overline{x}\exists\overline{y}\,\varphi(\overline{x},\overline{y})$, where $\varphi$ is quantifier-free. This is called the Chang-Łoś-Suszko theorem. It's one of the classical preservation results in model theory.

The counterexample above is an $\exists\forall$-sentence, with just one quantifier of each kind, which shows the Chang-Łoś-Suszko theorem can't be improved.